# Problem executing methods in lambda expressions menu

Tags: python, lambda

I am trying to implement the typical switch case menu in python using lambda statements. My code is the one below:

```
while(opcion!=3):
    opcion=raw_input('Seleccione la opcion :\n1-. Wifi\n2-. Eth\n3-. Salir\n')
    print type(opcion)
    opcion=int(opcion)
    result = {
        1: lambda x: fm._add_host_and_group(ip,usuario,tipo,'wifi',sede), # esta ip se deberia de coger del infoblox
        2: lambda x: fm._add_host_and_group(ip,usuario,tipo,'ethe',sede), # esta deberia estar ya creada, es bastante jodido identificar
        3: lambda x: None
    }
    idle=result.get(opcion,lambda:"error en el menu")
    print idle
```

I have validated the working mode of this kind of menu when each options of the menu assigns a value to a variable. For example the code below:

```
sede=input('Seleccione la sede del usuario:\n1-. Albia\n2-. Galindo\n3-. VA\n')
ip_pool = {
    1: lambda x: '10.10.200.0/23', 
    2: lambda x: '10.10.203.0/24', 
    3: lambda x: '10.10.202.0/24'
}[sede](x)
```

The problem appears when I try to execute different methods depending of each option of the menu. I have tried to change the code in several ways but I am not able to make it work. Does somebody know if it is possible this utility? If not, I could do a menu using if statements, but I would like to homogenize the code.

Comment: You never call the function that is assigned to `idle`.

Comment: how can I do this? sorry but I am lost with this kind of menus

Comment: `idle(x)`.  You will have to handle option `3` differently since you can't call `None` like a function.

Comment: Note that you never use the `x` arg in your lambdas - you can change them to simply `lambda: ...` then call it like `idle()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the answer of 0x5453 is the correct one:

idle(x). You will have to handle option 3 differently since you can't call None like a function.